# Questioning Mathematica's Condition Representation: Strange Solution for Integer Variable

Tags: assumptions, code-request

I have the following sequence:

$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 & \text { if } 0 \leq x<\frac{1}{2} \\
1-(n+1)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) & \text { if } \frac{1}{2} \leq x<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1} \\
0 & \text { if } \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq 1
\end{array}\right.$$

I would like to calculate
$$\left\|f_n-f_m\right\|^2 =\int_0^1\left|f_n(x)-f_m(x)\right|^2 \mathrm{~d} x$$

Then I wrote the following code

```
f[n_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= t < 1/2}, {1 - (n + 1) ( t - 1/2), 
    1/2 <= t < 1/2 + 1/(n + 1)}, {0, 1/2 + 1/(n + 1) <= t <= 1}}]

Integrate[(f[n] - f[m])^2, {t, -1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers, m > 0, 
   n > 0}]
```

produces the output:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{24}(m-n)^2 & 0<m \leq 1 \& \& 0<n \leq 1 \\ \frac{(m-n)^2}{3(1+n)^3} & (m-n=0 \& \&>1 \& \& n>1)||(m-n \geq 0 \& \& n \leq 0)|| m \leq 0||(m \leq 1 \& \& n \leq 0) \\ \frac{(m-n)^2}{3(1+m)(1+n)^2} & (m-n<0 \& \&>1 \& \& n>1)||(m-n<0 \& \&>1 \& \& n \leq 0) \\ \frac{(m-n)^2}{3(1+m)^2(1+n)} & m>1 \& \& m-n>0 \& n>1 \\ \frac{-1+4 m m^2-2 n-8 m n+2 m^2 n+7 n^2-4 m n^2+m^2 n^2}{24(1+n)^2} & 0<m \leq 1 \& \&>1 \\ \frac{-1-2 m+7 m^2+4 n-8 m n-4 m^2 n+n^2+2 m n^2+m^2 n^2}{24(1+m)^2} & \text { True }\end{cases}$$

I think that  the solution is a bit strange because, for example, in the first condition I read $0<m\leq 1$ but this means $m=1$ because $m$ is an integer; Why does Mathematica write the condition like this? And what does the last condition mean (TRUE)?

Comment: The last condition of a `Piecewise` (i.e., `True`) is the default condition -- for any input that does not match any of the specified conditions. If you use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` you can see that your third condition is merged with the default condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

```
sol=Integrate[(f[n] - f[m])^2, {t, -1, 1},Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers, m > 0, n > 0}]
```

we get simplified conditions

```
solNew = Simplify[sol[[1]] , Element[{n, m}, Integers]]
```

Final result

```
Apply[Which,Map[Reverse,solNew]//Flatten]
(*Which[m == 1 && n == 1,1/24 (m - n)^2, 
(m == n && m > 1 && 
n > 1) || (n <= 0 && (m >= n || m <= 1)) || m <= 0, (m - n)^2/(
3 (1 + n)^3), m < n && m > 1 && n != 1, (m - n)^2/(
3 (1 + m) (1 + n)^2), m > 1 && m > n && n > 1, (m - n)^2/(
3 (1 + m)^2 (1 + n)), 
m == 1 && n > 1, (-1 - 2 n + 7 n^2 + m^2 (1 + n)^2 - 
4 m (-1 + 2 n + n^2))/(24 (1 + n)^2)]*)
```

**addendum**

It even goes more direct

```
Apply[Piecewise,{solNew}]
```